# Does any spacetime admit a global foliation in spacelike hypersurfaces?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology

In the comments of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295015/25794) the following new questions came up: in general relativity, local coordinates can be found around any point, that single out a time coordinate and a three dimensional spatial submanifold, but in general it won't be possible to write spacetime globally as a product of a spacelike and a timelike submanifold.

If local coordinates around all points such that the locally spatial hyperplanes map into hyperplanes under a change of coordinates, then we got a [foliation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) of spacetime into spacelike hypersurfaces.

[image: foliation of spacetime]

I would be interested to know:

1. Does there always exist a global foliation of spacetime into spacelike hypersurfaces?
2. In such a foliation, are all leaves homeomorphic?

Comment: Note that most people think that a "well-behaved" spacetime must be a [globally hyperbolic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_hyperbolic_manifold) which fulfills the stronger condition of admitting a foliation by [Cauchy surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface), all of which are always diffeomorphic. I suspect that what you *really* want is such a Cauchy foliation and not simply a foliation into spacelike submanifolds.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/198552/13917 and links therein.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks a lot, this is very interesting.